# Create a pseudo random number from microsecond

Tags: python

I'm starting to learn python now, so I'm sorry if it's a stupid question, but I couldn't figure it out or find another question like this.  When I write

```
import datetime

datetime.datetime.now()
```

It generates a tuple, at least I suppose so because it's between parentesis `()`. I wanted to separate them in a list using `.split(',')` and then get the last number on the microsecond which would be a pseudo random number. Can anyone help me?

I solved my problem, I didn't knew there was a documetation explaining the classes! Thank you all for helping me! Here is how I solved it

```
    import datetime
    aee=datetime.datetime.isoformat(datetime.datetime.now())
    aee=aee[-1]
    print(aee)
```

Comment: While it's interesting for practicing, you should just `import random; random.randint(0, 9)`.

Comment: `now()` doesn't generate a tuple, it generates a `datetime` object. You can see that by printing it out: `datetime.datetime(2018, 3, 18, 13, 56, 10, 763983)`. And `datetime` objects have attributes and methods. Which you can look up with `help` in your REPL, or in the docs.

Comment: Look up the datetime type (it's not a tuple, despite the parentheses, because it has the name datetime.datetime before it) in the Python documentation and pick the last field. Parsing the printed form is a terrible idea. Also take care that this number is random enough for your purposes. It's probably better to use the 'random' module. (Times are often good for seeding random number generaters, though.)

Comment: Also, if it _were_ a tuple, you don't get values out of a tuple by converting it to a string, parsing the string, then converting the substring back to its original value. You just index it, like `tup[2]` (or iterate over it, like `for value in tup:`).

Comment: and by default `random` is seeded with the current time, so you don't have to do it, unlike with C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is simple solution. Does that meet your expectations?

```
import datetime
import math

# This prints microseconds of current time
print(datetime.datetime.now().microsecond)

# This is used to extract milliseconds
print(math.floor(datetime.datetime.now().microsecond / 1000))
```